# Wordpress PHP background padding changing?

Tags: php, html, css

There's a Wordpress site which I wrote in PHP.
I need to change the background image padding. I tried to change it in the base CSS but it won't work. If I use the Google inspect mode, I can change the padding and it works.

The site is:
https://www.sorridentefogaszat.hu/csapat/

Need to change the .subpage-container padding, now it's 570px 0 0 0 and I want to change 500px 0 0 0.

I used AcelIDE in Wordpress.

The team id has these code:

```
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
```

if I change the display, will the padding changing work?

Comment: It could be your browser caching the old CSS instead of rendering the updated one. Open your browser's Sources tab and make sure that it is your new CSS that is received, and not an old one.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, the old css try to play a trick with me :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is working on Chrome's inspect tool but not in CSS, it could be a browser cache issue.

What I mean is your browser could be caching the old CSS instead of rendering the updated one. To make sure, open your browser's Sources tab and check that it is your new CSS that is received, and not an old one (or simply empty your browser cache and reload the page).

Edit: As @noob_kid pointed out, your CSS change does show in their browser, which is loading the page for the first time I assume (=> has no prior browser cache). This consolidates my suspicion that it is indeed a browser cache issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, the old css try to play a trick with me :)

Comment: @ZsofiaLakatos Glad this helps! If this answered your question, please consider upvoting/marking this as answer. Have a good day!

Answer (score -1):

I think you have did it already....[image]